# Detecting touch coordinates in Android

Tags: android, touch, drawing, touch-event

I want to detect touch coordinates, but not coordinates of the point of touch. For example, if I touch the screen, I want that all area of finger, which touched the screen was painted. Methods getX() and getY() of touchEvent gave me only coordinates of one point, as I understand. How can I solve my problem?

Now I have application, where user can only draw points or lines, but I want, that size and form of lines of points was like size and form of finger, which touched the screen.

Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dv = new DrawingView(this);
    setContentView(dv);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(120);  
}

public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int width;
    public  int height;
    private Bitmap  mBitmap;
    private Canvas  mCanvas;
    private Path    mPath;
    private Paint   mBitmapPaint;
    Context context;
    private Paint circlePaint;
    private Path circlePath;

    public DrawingView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        context=c;
        mPath = new Path();
        mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);  
        circlePaint = new Paint();
        circlePath = new Path();
        circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        circlePaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
        circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f); 


    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.drawBitmap( mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);

        canvas.drawPath( mPath,  mPaint);

        canvas.drawPath( circlePath,  circlePaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX)/2, (y + mY)/2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;

            circlePath.reset();
            circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        }
    }
    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        circlePath.reset();
        // commit the path to our offscreen
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath,  mPaint);
        // kill this so we don't double draw
        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it but [MotionEvent.getSize()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getSize%28%29) sounds like it could help you. Even though you wont get precise coordinates you probably will be able to get an estimation with the method's result, screen size and the coordinates of the touch event...

Let me know whether it's what you needed, sounds interesting.